# Search collection in Typescript for partial string match

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, linq, asp.net-core

I want to search collection in typescript as we can search in SQL and linq with like operator in sql and contain method in linq i.e in sql

```
name like ‘%searchString%’
```

and in linq

```
query = query.Where(x => x.UserName.ToLower().Contains(queryObj.SearchStr.ToLower()));
```

Is there a way we can do this operation in typescript? To search a collection of strings for items with partial match?

Thank you

Comment: can you provide sample data ?

Comment: You may consider any type of data in collection

Comment: `String.prototype.includes()` might be what you're looking for `query.filter(e => e.includes("searchString"))`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: `filter` should work

Comment: @Arghya C, filter, search a complete string not a part of string for example if string is a stackOverflow and I want to search a word "over" then filter method will not search word stackOverflow,

Comment: @Arghya C, filter with include is working well, thank you

Comment: Updating the question to better reflect intent

Comment: @ArghyaC if you don't want the output in array but want to find a value then try my answer.

Comment: @anonymous umm...but OP didn't ask for that

Comment: That's for his knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Javascript `filter` array function. `filter` returns the items in an array where the expression evaluates to a truthy result.

You can use the `includes` string function to see if a string exists inside another string.

```js
const values = [
  'abc',
  'aYz',
  'xyz'
];

const filtered = values.filter(x => x.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('y'));

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr: string[] = ['paris', 'berlin', 'delhi', 'istanbul'];

const result: string[] = arr.filter(key => key.toLowerCase().includes('in'));
```

Answer (score 1):

To find one value. The result isn't an array here. It returns berlin.

```js
const values = ['paris', 'berlin', 'delhi', 'istanbul'];

const filtered = values.find(x => x.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('in'));

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.UserName.ToLower().Contains(queryObj.SearchStr.ToLower()));
```

TypeScript/JavaScript

```
query = query.filter(x => x.userName.toLowerCase().includes(queryObj.SearchStr.toLowerCase()))
```